# TFS build template to take the drop (artefacts) from the CI build and execute Integration Tests

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, build-definition

I have managed to chain two TFS builds together using [Jason Stangroome's chaining build definition template](http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/). This gives me the capacity to execute one build definition after the next:

1. CertificateRepository-CI (Continuous Integration Build)
2. CertificateRepository-IntegrationTests

The latter will automatically be executed if the former is successful. I am stumped by the lack of Build Definition Templates that are able to download and extract the contents of the preceding build's drop folder and perform actions upon these artifacts, in this case running SpecFlow/NUnit integration tests.

In this case I am using:

- Visual Studio Online
- Git for the codebase being tested
- TFVC for the ALM components (NUnit Adapter, Build Definition Templates)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using TFS for source control**: I don't have a template for this but you can follow below steps to achieve this.

- In CI build set the **Staging Location** option to **Copy buildoutput to following Source Control folder**
- Download the drop folder by mapping it in source settings option
  in build definition
- Under drop location folder in TFS, every CI build will create a new folder, you need to pass this folder name to the second build definition. Please check another [post](http://blog.stangroome.com/2014/02/19/queue-a-team-build-from-another-and-pass-parameters/) from Jason for passing parameters to second build
- Execute the tests by invoking the commandline tools using Invoke
  Process activity.

Comment: Thank You - is this is effectively checking it into source control?

Comment: Yes, it will check-in the build output in TFS source control.

Comment: As it turns out this isn't an option if you are using Git for your repository, it does however work perfectly if you are using TFVC.